# passing textbox value to controller on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass textbox data to controller action on a button click. Here is my code:

```
<input id="txt" type="text">
<button onclick="@Url.Action("MyAction", "Mycontroller", new {currencyCode=ViewBag .currencyCode,endDate=Model.StartDate, value entered in txt above})" >
```

I cant use form here. Can you please suggest me how I can access/ pass this value to action ?

Thanks for your help and guiding me.

Comment: Your controller works only with POST data or with GET too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like

```
<div>
  <input type='text' name='UnboundTextBoxName' />
</div>
```

MVC will automatically take the value of UnboundTextBoxName and insert that value into the parameter of the same name.

Answer (score 6):

The code below sends the text-box value to the controller's action.

```
<input id="txt" type="text">
<button id="button">Click Me</button>

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#button").click(function () {
            var txtVal = $("#txt").val();
            window.location = "@Url.Action("TheAction","TheController")" + 
                              "/" + txtVal;
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Hi this is great, but the text is not getting passes into my controller method. How can I debug this function to see what is happening?

Comment: The JavaScript code makes a URL like this: www.example.com/TheController/TheAction/TheText. If the "TheAction" method of your controller has a parameter, it will have the "TheText" as its parameter. The RouteData has also the "TheText".

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `<form>` tags and set the action to your controller and have set a place in your model to store the data.

Comment: +1, for a good suggestion. It would be ideal to provide solution

Answer (score 0):

This would help you get the value entered in the text box to be the part of the url and in turn hit the required action in your controller specified

```
<form id = "form1" runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox id= "txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <input type="button" id = "searchbtn" value="Search" onclick="srch_Click()"/>
</form>

<script type ="text/javascript" >
function srch_Click() {
        var host = window.location.host;
        var txt = $("#txtbox").val();
        var path = "/CONTROLLER/ACTION/" + txt;
        window.location.pathname = path;
        var url = host + path;
        window.location(url);
    }
</script>
```

any improvisation to the above code is welcomed